# custom bootstrap scrollbar with ul li

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please see my fiddle location:

http://jsfiddle.net/shalinid/W4JKM/44/

I found custom bootstrap scroll bar from http://jsfiddle.net/W4JKM/

I want to include my menu inside the scroll bar.  My div width is 50px. So i fixed the width 50px to the scroll bar.  Normally it shows fine. If I scroll the menu, and hover the link, the sub menu position is changed.

Kindly solve my issue.

```
$('#scrollbox3').enscroll({
    showOnHover: false,
    verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
    verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
});
```

Comment: I cant see what you mention in your fiddle, are you sure the fiddle address is correct?

Comment: Where is the menu? :)

Comment: sorry. Kindly see the edited fiddle location.

Comment: @Akash - I update the fiddle below - did you get a solution at all?

Answer (score 1):

You need to position your submenu *relative* to the parent list item.

As such, give the parent `li` `position:relative`, and then you can, e.g. add `position:absolute` to the submenu.

There is a lot of HTML/CSS in your fiddle so there will be a more elegant way to implement with your code, but by way of an example, you can use the following CSS:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/W4JKM/46/)

```
.left_menu ul li{
    position:relative;
}
.submenu{
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:0;
}
```